# How can I upgrade my OS X 10.4.11 to Snow Leopard and then Mavericks?

Tags: imac, upgrade, powerpc, macos

I am on iMac PowerPC with OS X 10.4.11
Can I upgrade to Snow Leopard and then to Mavericks?
If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

PowerPC is only supported up until Mac Os X 10.5 (Leopard), so Mavericks is out of the question. Snow Leopard (10.6) is also too high. 10.5 is the highest possible.